# Starting another project in the solution in Debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, process

I am working on two processes that interact with each other via named pipes. Process#1 is running in debug mode and it starts Process#2 with `Process.Start("process name")` I want to run this process#2 on debug mode also, using breakpoints. 
How can I do this?

I have tried using "Attach to Process" tool in Visual Studio 2008 but it's not very practical when you are in the development process. You need to start Process#2 in order to attach to it. I want Process#2 to be started directly in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have same solution for this projects then you can use multiple start in solution properties (Solution properties->Startup Project)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it won't help me much because my requirement insists that 2nd app is started by the 1st app. I don't want both apps start one after another when I hit F5.

Answer (score 4):

Put this line in the Main() method of the 2nd project:

```
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

That brings up the just-in-time debugger prompt as soon as the 2nd process starts running.  You can pick either a new or an existing instance of visual studio to debug it.  Use Debug + Step Out to get back into managed code.

Answer (score 2):

Go to solution properties in VS. Opt for multiple startup project. Unless your requirement insist opening of second app from first, this should work fine.

Comment: but what if you do depend on another project loading first?